# SD: Configuring GAM External Authentication

Tags: genexus, genexus-gam

I am trying to setup GAM using External Authentication.
I created my own procedure (exposed as webservice) to consume the external authentication services and return the &GAMWSLoginOutSDT GAM is expecting.

According to documentation, this procedure has to have exposed Namespace = "GAM" (meaning it has to be "Main Program" with Call Protocol "SOAP", right?)
But, as soon as I set Call Protocol "SOAP", I no longer can access the service URL in the browser:

```
http://localhost/myApp/app.wslogingam.svc
```

Is returns an error:

> The type 'GeneXus.Programs.app.wslogingam_services,app.awslogingam', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

I have already implemented this solution before for other Apps, but, for this one, I am stuck with this problem.

Maybe it's the genexus version ev3 u2 (beta)? (in previous versions, I used the prefix "a" for the exposed services, now it's "app.")

Can you please help?

GAM instructions I am trying to follow:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?GAM+External+Authentication%3A+version+1.0,

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to solve the problem by setting the MainProgram of the procedure to "False" (I can still use it for GAM this way).

For some reason, setting it to "true" causes the error above.